# Clustered barchart in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

How do I plot a barchart similar to

[Clustered bar plot in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5130517/clustered-bar-plot-in-gnuplot#) using python matplotlib?

```
date|name|empid|app|subapp|hours
20140101|A|0001|IIC|I1|2.5
20140101|A|0001|IIC|I2|3
20140101|A|0001|IIC|I3|4
20140101|A|0001|CAR|C1|2.5
20140101|A|0001|CAR|C2|3
20140101|A|0001|CAR|C3|2
20140101|A|0001|CAR|C4|2
```

Trying to plot the subapp hours by app for the same person.  Couldn't see an example in the demo pages of matplotlib.

EDIT: None of the examples cited below seem to work for unequal # of bars for each category as above.

Comment: There *is* [an example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html)

Comment: and [another](http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html) example

Comment: Btw, the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11597785/setting-spacing-between-grouped-bar-plots-in-matplotlib) explains a few things you may want to have into account

Comment: `subapp` values does not match between `app`s. length: 3 vs 4, names: `I*` vs `C*`.

Comment: subapp can be any number of entries for IIC/CAR and need not match.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll try them out close out the question, if I can get it to work.

Comment: None of the examples work if I choose unequal # of bars for each category. Unless I'm doing something wrong.  The above data has unequal number of entries for each category I* and C*

Comment: Pad out your categories to contain the same number of subapps?

Answer (score 1):

The examples didn't manage unequal # of bars but you can use another approach. I'll post you an example.

Note: I use pandas to *manipulate* your data, if you don't know about it you should give it a try http://pandas.pydata.org/:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_table("data.csv",sep="|")
grouped = df.groupby('app')['hours']

colors = "rgbcmyk"

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
initial_gap = 0.1
start = initial_gap
width = 1.0
gap = 0.05
for app,group in grouped:
    size = group.shape[0]
    ind = np.linspace(start,start + width, size+1)[:-1]   
    w = (ind[1]-ind[0])
    start = start + width + gap
    plt.bar(ind,group,w,color=list(colors[:size]))

tick_loc = (np.arange(len(grouped)) * (width+gap)) + initial_gap + width/2
ax.set_xticklabels([app for app,_ in grouped])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mtick.FixedLocator(tick_loc))

plt.show()
```

And on **data.csv** is the *data*:

```
date|name|empid|app|subapp|hours
20140101|A|0001|IIC|I1|2.5
20140101|A|0001|IIC|I2|3
20140101|A|0001|IIC|I3|4
20140101|A|0001|CAR|C1|2.5
20140101|A|0001|CAR|C2|3
20140101|A|0001|CAR|C3|2
20140101|A|0001|CAR|C4|2
```